# Trying to make ruby-install on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-install

I downloaded ruby-install version 0.6.1 and for some reason I get this make error:

> *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

What can I do to fix this?

```
deploy@blah:~$ sudo ls /root/
ruby-install-0.6.1  ruby-install.tar.gz

deploy@blah:~$ sudo make /root/ruby-install-0.6.1/ install
make: Nothing to be done for '/root/ruby-install-0.6.1/'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

**Update**

**I went into the directory now:**

```
root@blah:~/ruby-install-0.6.1# sudo make install
for dir in `find bin share -type d`; do mkdir -p /usr/local/$dir; done
for file in `find bin share -type f`; do cp $file /usr/local/$file; done
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/doc/ruby-install-0.6.1
cp -r *.md *.txt /usr/local/share/doc/ruby-install-0.6.1/
```

Did this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `cd` into the directory, not pass the directory as an argument to `make`. E.g.

```
cd ruby-install-0.6.1
sudo make install
```

Comment: Please see my update, it just outputted all these commands after running make, is this correct?

Comment: @Blankman If you try to run `ruby-install`, does it succeed? (You may have to start a new shell, depending on your configuration).

Comment: Yes it works.  Strange when I manually ssh into the server it works.  When I used ansible I got that error.  Must be something in this command: https://github.com/aleks/ansible-rails/blob/master/roles/ruby/tasks/ruby-install.yml#L10